# How can I pass arguments to an exe I am calling ( via CreateProcess )?

Tags: c++, executable

I have a sleeper.exe.

The main method to sleeper.exe is:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    SleeperClass sleeper;
    sleeper.sleep();
    return 0;

}
```

and the Sleeper class is:

using namespace std;

```
SleeperClass::SleeperClass() {
}

SleeperClass::SleeperClass(const SleeperClass& orig) {
}

SleeperClass::~SleeperClass() {
}

void SleeperClass::sleep() {

    cout << "Message 1\n";
    Sleep(2000);
    cout << "Message 2 a two seconds after Message 1";

}
```

What I want to achieve is this. I want to call sleeper.exe from createprocess.exe. But I want to be able to pass the variable to tell sleeper exe to sleep as long as I want. ( instead of 2000 )

Here is my createprocess.exe source:

```
int main(int argc, TCHAR *argv[]) {

    std::ifstream myReadFile;
    myReadFile.open("config.mpap");

    char output[400];
    if (myReadFile.is_open()) {
        while (!myReadFile.eof()) {
            myReadFile >> output;
        }
    }
    myReadFile.close();

    std::cout << "\n";
    char x = output[19];
    int numberOfChildren = x - '0';
    char y = output[37];
    int numberOfSleeps = y - '0';
    char z = output[49];
    int sleepTime = z - '0';

    std::cout << "Number of children: ";
    std::cout << numberOfChildren;
    std::cout << "\n";
    std::cout << "Number of sleeps: ";
    std::cout << numberOfSleeps;
    std::cout << "\n";
    std::cout << "Sleep Time: ";
    std::cout << sleepTime;
    std::cout << "\n";

    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof (si));
    si.cb = sizeof (si);
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof (pi));


    while (numberOfSleeps > 0) {
        std::cout<<"Child process being created";
        --numberOfSleeps;

    // Start the child process. 
    if (!CreateProcess("c:\\sleeper.exe", // No module name (use command line)
            argv[1], // Command line
            NULL, // Process handle not inheritable
            NULL, // Thread handle not inheritable
            FALSE, // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
            0, // No creation flags
            NULL, // Use parent's environment block
            NULL, // Use parent's starting directory 
            &si, // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
            &pi) // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
            ) {
        printf("CreateProcess failed (%d).\n", GetLastError());
        return 0;
    }

    std::cout << pi.dwProcessId;
    std::cout << "\n";

    }

    // Wait until child process exits.
    WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);

    // Close process and thread handles. 
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);



    return 0;
}
```

How can I pass the **sleepTime** to sleeper.exe?

Thanks.

Edit: I can not use command line because I am reading the parameters from a file.

Comment: Without command line parameters. This is my best try. @nvoigt

Comment: I'm not sure why you can use the command line parameters if you are reading them from a file. You first read them and than pass them to the child process. (There is a point at which you know the sleep value - this is when you could call the subprocess). Otherwise you could use shared memory for example.

Either way you go, you will first need to know the sleep value before being able to pass it to the child process.

Comment: And why is it 'without command line parameters'? I mean, it's most obvious, logic, simplest and optimal way to do so - so is there any single reason not to use them?

Comment: "because I am reading the parameters from a file." did you just answer your own question? Read the parameters from the file.Also don't forget to pass the value into `Sleep()` with a method argument.

Comment: @MaxShifrin  You first read them and than pass them to the child process. How???

Comment: You can read parameters from file by opening the file and reading from it. Here's a nice tutorial: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sleeper.exe

```
void SleeperClass::sleep(int sleeptime) {

    cout << "Message 1\n";
    Sleep(sleeptime);
    cout << "Message 2 a two seconds after Message 1";

}
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int sleeptime=2000;      //default sleeptime is 2000
    if(argc>=2)     //if  sleeper.exe has any params and the first param is sleeptime
    {
        sleeptime=atoi(argv[1]);    // here you should check whether argv[1] is legal
    }
    SleeperClass sleeper;
    sleeper.sleep(sleeptime);
    return 0;

}
```

in cmdline you just type  `sleeper.exe 1000`  it will sleep 1000ms

createprocess.exe source:

```
 ...
 char sleeptime_str[10];
 itoa(sleepTime,sleeptime_str);
 if (!CreateProcess("c:\\sleeper.exe", // No module name (use command line)
            sleeptime_str, // Command line the param is sleeptime_str
            NULL, // Process handle not inheritable
            NULL, // Thread handle not inheritable
            FALSE, // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
            0, // No creation flags
            NULL, // Use parent's environment block
            NULL, // Use parent's starting directory 
            &si, // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
            &pi) // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
            ) {
        printf("CreateProcess failed (%d).\n", GetLastError());
        return 0;
    }

 ...
```

and the itoa function

```
void itoa(int value, char *str)
{
    if (value < 0)  

    {
        str[0] = '-';
        value = 0-value;
    }
    int i,j;
    for(i=1; value > 0; i++,value/=10)  

        str[i] = value%10+'0';  

    for(j=i-1,i=1; j-i>=1; j--,i++)  

    {
        str[i] = str[i]^str[j];
        str[j] = str[i]^str[j];
        str[i] = str[i]^str[j];
    }
    if(str[0] != '-')  

    {
        for(i=0; str[i+1]!='\0'; i++)
            str[i] = str[i+1];
        str[i] = '\0';
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not help me at all. Thanks anyway.

Comment: how? have you recompiled the  sleeper.exe

Comment: I think itoa is not recognized by my compiler.

Comment: have you  include <stdlib.h>? if your compiler still can not recognize itoa you can Implement this method by yourself

Comment: This function is not defined in ANSI-C and is not part of C++, but is supported by some compilers.
I am very new to C++ so it is very difficult for me to implement it myself.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I am almost there but I still cant make it work. How can I start a chat with you?

Comment: email is ok zzh2@shu.edu.cn

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41797/discussion-between-koray-tugay-and-patato)